# Querying two tables with columns named the same

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables in a SQL Server database: `table1` and `table2`

table1:

```
 DATE        NAME    CREDIT
 1/1/2011    BALU      100 
 1/3/2011    BALU      200
```

table2:

```
 DATE        NAME    DEBIT
 1/2/2011    BALU      100 
 1/3/2011    BALU       50
```

I want to display the report in following format:

```
 DATE        NAME    CREDIT  DEBIT
 1/1/2011    BALU      100      0
 1/2/2011    BALU        0    100
 1/3/2011    BALU      200     50
```

My problem is that both tables have a `date` column.

How can I write the `SELECT` statement with a `WHERE` clause given that both tables have the same column named `date`?

Comment: Please specify a problem you are having and clarify your question. Your apparent problem does not coincide with your title or it's unclear.

Comment: now you can understand my question?

Comment: I added the SUM operation, assuming there can be several Credited or Debited operations the same day. (I am also assuming you are using only the DATE part and not TIME).

Comment: thanks friends i got the answer form AJC

Comment: yes i don't need to check the time. you give the correct qry for my current problem. once again i thanks to you.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am still not positive about what you want, several details are missing. But based on experience working in similar queries I think this is what you might need (or close enough).

```
SELECT ISNULL(C.DATE, D.DATE) DATE, ISNULL(C.NAME, D.NAME) NAME, SUM(C.CREDIT) CREDIT, SUM(D.DEBIT) DEBIT
FROM TABLE_1 C
FULL JOIN TABLE2 D ON D.DATE=C.DATE AND D.NAME=C.NAME
WHERE ISNULL(C.DATE, D.DATE) BETWEEN @DATE1 AND @DATE2
GROUP BY C.DATE, D.DATE, C.NAME, D.NAME
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. this qry solve my problem. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Sure thing, english isn't my native tongue either... Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, thi is what you want:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(T1.Date,T2.Date) Date, ISNULL(T1.Name,T2.Name) Name, 
        ISNULL(T1.Credit,0) Credit, ISNULL(T2.Debit,0) Debit
FROM table1 T1
FULL JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.Date = T2.Date AND T1.Name = T2.Name
```

Comment: sorry it display duplicate records

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.[DATE], t2.[DATE]) [DATE], 
    COALESCE(t1.[NAME], t2.[NAME]) [NAME], 
    COALESCE(t1.[CREDIT], 0) [CREDIT], 
    COALESCE(t2.[DEBIT], 0) [DEBIT]
  FROM Table1 t1
  FULL JOIN Table2 t2 
    ON (t1.[DATE] = t2.[DATE]) AND (t1.[NAME] = t2.[NAME])
```

Comment: sorry the above qry return duplicate records

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the datediff function in sql.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189794.aspx
Still i might be wrong since your question is not clearly stated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify which date is first in the between and the FK linking both table, i will assume..

```
 select ta.date, ta.name, ta.credit, tb.debit from table1 ta
 join table2 tb as (ta.name = tb.name)
 where ta.date between tb.date
```

Comment: that is my problem both table have date column the above example table1 transaction is date 1 and 3 table2 transaction is date 2 and 3 so how can i display the date correctly. when i execute user qry i get correct result?